# Location Tracking in every 1 minute

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating a xamarin form app which require user location (user's longitude and latitude) after every 1 minute whether app is running in foreground or background.
I am able to get user location after every 1 minute if user stays at one position or moving slowly.

But Facing issue in getting location when user is in situation like riding bike or moving in speed,
I am not able to get user's location (user longitude and latitude) in such situatiion.

```
try
                {
                    if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable)
                    {
                        if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationEnabled)
                        {
                            count += 1;

                            // var location = await GetLocationFromPhone().ConfigureAwait(false);
                            var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.High, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
                            if (location != null)
                            {
                            
                                var model = new lat_lon
                                {
                                    lat = location.Latitude,
                                    lon = location.Longitude,
                                    dist = count
                                };
                                MessagingCenter.Send<lat_lon>(model, "LocationLngLet");
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
               catch (TargetInvocationException srtiex)
                {
                  
                }
                catch (IllegalStateException ilsex)
                {
                  
                }
                catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneex)
                {
                 
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException nrex)
                {
                
                }
                catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
                {
                }
                catch (PermissionException pEx)
                {
                    // Handle permission exception                
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    // Unable to get location              
                }
```

Suggest any solution for this issue!!

Comment: Where is the relevant code?

Comment: i have updated the post with relevant code.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: while testing, i am not getting my location while riding bike.
but working fine, getting location when i stay at one position or moving slowly

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?  All of your catch blocks are empty.  Are you using a timer to call this every 10s?

Comment: i am not getting any exception
and yes i am using timer to update location in every 10 s

Comment: location is not stored on server when user riding bike or moving faster

Answer (score 1):

This should run in a service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/ , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-walkthroughs/location-walkthrough), because you need it to work no matter the phone's/app's state. Consider using LocationManagers for each project and set the properties you need for locationChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [GeolocatorPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin), right?

And from the [Geolocator Plugin documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/), especially  [Listing For Location Changes](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/LocationChanges.html)  and [Background Updates](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/BackgroundUpdates.html), we see:

Before subscribing to events you must start listening, which will start the managers to query for location changes.

To check to see if you are listning there is a nifty `IsListening` property on the `CrossGeolocator.Current` that you can use.

```
bool IsListening { get; }
```

Once you are ready to start listening for changes you can call the `StartListeningAsync`. After this, you can add event handlers to get the changes.

```
 Task<bool> StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan minimumTime, double minimumDistance, bool includeHeading = false, ListenerSettings listenerSettings = null);
```

**Note:**

`ListenerSettings` are details more in the [Background Updates documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/BackgroundUpdates.html).

And background updates are handled a bit different on each platform. The [Driving application](https://github.com/azure-samples/mydriving) is a great sample showing how to handle this on all mobile platforms.

For more details, you can check:

https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/BackgroundUpdates.html